# What algorithms do you know for beltway reconstruction?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, backtracking

I've faced the beltway reconstruction problem and I've developed a simple backtrack algorithm, what algorithms do you know for this problem? 
**Beltway Reconstruction Problem**: 
Assume there is a set of non-identical integers between 0 and N, we only have pairwise distances of points of that set mod N, How can we reconstruct the original set using this?

Comment: Have you looked at "Reconstructing Sets From Interpoint Distances"?

Comment: Yes, It suggests two methods for turnpike reconstruction problem and one method for beltway reconstruction problem. But it is so old, I'm looking for newly developed algorithms.